# How to convert xml String into class object in java using soap web service

Tags: java, soap

## im trying to typecast class object with JAXB ##

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc.class);
    org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.ServiceLT service = new org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.ServiceLT();
    org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.ServiceLTSoap port = service.getServiceLTSoap12();
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    //org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult xmldoc = (org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult  xmldoc = (org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource);

```
String result=port.getSurveyResult(xmldoc);
```

Comment: im using JABXContext to convert xml string as class object i.e(org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult)
but in my WS method giving error:

Required :org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.XmlDoc
FOund : java.lang.String.

could u hlp me

Thanks in advs

Comment: could you provide exact exception logs....so that it would be easy to check which call throws this error

Comment: im getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult cannot be cast to org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult$Xmldoc
        at test.getsurvey.main(getsurvey.java:32)

Comment: Following is my getsurveyResult method code which contains
1.public class getSurveyResult.
2 static class XmlDoc


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "xmldoc"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getSurveyResult")
public class GetSurveyResult {

    protected GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc xmldoc;

    
    public GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc getXmldoc() {
        return xmldoc;
    }
    public void setXmldoc(GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc value) {
        this.xmldoc = value;
    }
 
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "any"
    })